# How do I programmatically generate a menu based on field values?

Tags: entities, routes

I'm working on a site where I want to have a menu that displays links based off of the content of a certain field.

For example, lets say it is `int field_apples`. I want to automatically generate a menu that will have links to lists of articles with each value of apples (or a range of apples such as ≤9 apples).

- Apples menu

  - 1 apple
  - 2 apples
  - 3 apples
  - 7 apples
  - 9 or more apples

Each link above will show a list of articles for that particular value of apples.

Comment: using views consider an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved by using taxonomy to define your terms and the [Taxonomy Menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module to create the menu from these terms. Taxonomy is the preferred method for categorising content.

Comment: There are too many permutations to use taxonomies. In the example above I can have any number of "apples", and I need to create a menu with a link to a list of pages based on the number of "apples" each has. And I need to do this for a lot of different "fruits".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything that will programmatically build a list based on each value of a field. Instead I had to use views to build a report for each possible value of the field. I used a list of integers to keep the permutations manageable. This is far from ideal, but workable. It just means I have a lot more work to do to maintain it if I make any changes.